# C# Creating fractals using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

tried searching online, but could only find bits and bobs of outdated info on this.
Essentially I'm trying to write a program that draws a square (and circle) fractals using recursion.
For the square part I'm trying to draw a square within a field, then using recursion it would reduce its size by 50% (so half) and rotate it 90 degrees, and repeat depending on the recursion depth that's entered by the user.

Admittedly I haven't made that much progress but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as I'm struggling with understanding how to go about this.

Specifically with how I would create a recursive function that would reduce the size of the square and then rotate it by 90 degrees and draw it.

```
namespace MD2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int recursionDepth;
        bool drawCircle, drawSquare;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void drawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            recursionDepth = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            if (drawSquare == true)
            {
                textBox3.Text = "Square is being drawn"; //used for testing pursposes
                DrawRectangle();
            }

            if(drawCircle == true) //used later when something similar to squares will be drawn
            {
                textBox3.Text = "Circles are being drawn";
            }
        }

public void DrawRectangle()
        {
/*/////////////////////////////////////
        Graphics dc = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        Point[] points =
    {
                new Point(0, 0),
                new Point(0, 400),
                new Point(0, 400),
                new Point(400,400),
                new Point(400, 0),
                new Point(0,0),
                };
            dc.DrawLines(myPen, points);
    }*///////////////////////////////////

//Two options, either drawing a square or drawing lines that form a square.

            Graphics dc = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
            int width = 400;
            int height = 400;


            for (int i = 0; i <4; i++) //experimenting with for loops, but recursions would be necessary
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width/2, height/2);
                dc.DrawRectangle(myPen, rect);
            }

}

        private void circle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawSquare = false;
            drawCircle = true;
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "Circle option selected"; //using for testing at this stage
        }


        private void square_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawCircle = false;
            drawSquare = true;
            textBox4.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "Square option selected"; //using for testing at this stage
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies for it being too long, but I wasnt sure if only parts of it would make sense.

The end result for the square would be something like this:
[image]

and the end result for the circle part would look like this:
[image]

Any pointers, criticisms or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How would a fractal code date??

Comment: Do not use `CreateGraphics` - do all your painting in the Paint event which will supply you with a valid `Graphics` object.  Do you know how to create a recursive method? Have you tried? What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how a recursive function can be used to draw the circles. You need to specify the initial state (center of the first circle, how much smaller the new circles should be after each iteration) and when the recursive method should terminate. If you forget that the program will crash with a stack overflow exception.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int initialRadius = 120; 
        const int centerX = 400; 
        const int centerY = 200;

        const double factor = 0.45; // Factor to determine the size of the next smaller radius

        const int recursionDepth = 5;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            DrawRecursionStage(centerX, centerY, initialRadius, e.Graphics);
        }

        private void DrawRecursionStage(int x, int y, int radius, Graphics g)
        {
            if (IsRecursionDepthReached(radius))
                return;

            DrawCircle(x, y, radius, g);

            int newRadius = (int)(radius * factor);
            DrawRecursionStage(x - radius, y, newRadius, g);
            DrawRecursionStage(x, y - radius, newRadius, g);
            DrawRecursionStage(x + radius, y, newRadius, g);
            DrawRecursionStage(x, y + radius, newRadius, g);
        }

        private void DrawCircle(int x, int y, int radius, Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
        }

        private static bool IsRecursionDepthReached(int radius)
        {
            return radius < Math.Pow(factor, recursionDepth) * initialRadius;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot more than I was expecting, thank you.
How would I define where it should draw the picture with the above? I.e. right now its drawing it on the form, but I'd like it to be drawn on the dedicated 'pictureBox1'

Comment: You can change the centerX and centerY coordinates to change where the circles are drawn. According to the documentation a PictureBox is designed to show an image (e.g. a bitmap) but if you want to draw lines, rectangles etc. you should use the 'e.Graphis' object in the `OnPaint` method. See [How to: Draw a Line on a Windows Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-a-line-on-a-windows-form) and [PictureBox Control (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/picturebox-control-windows-forms)

Comment: Oh right. I guess that makes more sense.
And how would I change it to not be a const recursionDepth as this would be entered by the user in the textBox1.Text field?

Comment: You can remove `const` on the line `const int recursionDepth = 5;` so it becomes a field and the user can change it. You also need to remove `static` from `IsRecursionDepthReached`.

Comment: Kept crashing when I did that, so thought I was doing something wrong. Turned out to be unrelated. My PC is just old.
Thank you very much for the help Marius!

Comment: This works great with few minor issues Im having - is it possible to make it so it only runs that function when a button and recursionDepth value is entered? i.e. the user has to put in a number and click the 'Draw' button. It doesnt seem to want to do that. It just draws a circle as soon as it launches and no amount of 'if' statements help